# Knockout doesn't bind selectedValue in a select properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-2.0

It seems impossible and I have tried a few different ways to create a select list and bind a value to it.

Firstly, and more desirably, I want to do it with Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedTemplate", Model.Templates, new { @data_bind = "value: Template()" })
```

The options are just an array of strings. When I bind with Razor then it's a List of SelectListItem objects with Text and Value equal to the same string.
So it renders like this:

```
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
```

When I bind via Knockout then the Templates is an array of strings:

```
var Templates ='["A", "B", "C"]';
```

which I generate in the cshtml file:

```
var Templates ='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Templates.Select(x=> x.Value)))';
```

Both create the same markup in HTML.  This renders the select list correctly. `Template()` prints out the correct value, for example "B". However, the drop down doesn't pick the option that is equal to `Template()`. I also tried:

```
<select name="SelectedTemplate" data-bind="value: Template(), options: JSON.parse(Templates)"></select>
```

Same problem here. And I tried all kinds of variations:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTemplate, Model.Templates, new { @class = "form-control layoutTemplateSelector", @data_bind = "value: Template(), options: JSON.parse(Templates)" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTemplate, Model.Templates, new { @class = "form-control layoutTemplateSelector", @data_bind = "value: Template()" })

@Html.DropDownList("SelectedTemplate", Model.Templates, new { @data_bind = "value: Template(), options: JSON.parse(Templates)" })
```

Ideally, I want to use `DropDownListFor` because on post back I want `m.SelectedTemplate` to be processed.

The postback works well so far for `DropDownListFor`, but on load it doesn't show the `data-bind: value:Template()`, which definitely contains the correct value.

I also tried your idea to use observable array with no success:

```
self.SelectedContent({              
            Template: ko.observable(content.Template()),
            TemplateList: ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(Templates))
        });

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Form.Template, Model.Templates, new {@data_bind = "value: Template(), options: TemplateList()" })
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here? I'm using Knockout 2.3 and MC.

### UPDATE

I found the error.

The value returned from the database contained a space: "A "
whereas the values binding the to the drop down didn't have that space.
This caused all the errors.

As far as I can see the simplest of implementations works well now:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedTemplate", Model.Templates, new { @data_bind = "value: Template()" })
```

Even though it was entirely my mistake, I hope it helps someone in the future. The error wasn't immediately apparent

Comment: What is the actual value of `Template()` and what are the `<option>`s in your drop-down?

Comment: On  your client side (KO) viewModel, do you have the Templates array ready and populated from the server side list? can you share the Ko view model source here?

Comment: Updated question with more details. The client side contains a very, very complicated viewmodel. But basically Template() prints out a string equal to the option value (and text). If you want any specific aspect of it, I'll add it. On the same page I have other data-binds which work well, for example in textareas or text controls.

Comment: "When I bind via Knockout then the Templates is an array of strings: `var Templates = '["A", "B", "C"]';`" - is `Templates` an observable object that is hooked up via Knockout?

Comment: No, I generate Templates in the razor file like this:
var Templates ='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Templates.Select(x=> x.Value)))';

Comment: do you see any client side js error?

Comment: no errors on client side.

Comment: Ah! Did you try the value binding without the brackets .. value : Template ..>